# How do +Dodge skills and passives stack in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I have a Monk with 25% dodge if I use nothing by my Dex score. If I add a passive that gives +15% dodge, the final dodge chance only increases to 36.2; with Mantra of Evasion active (which gives another +15% dodge) the final dodge change increases to 45.8%; if Mantra of Evasion is within three seconds of being cast, than it offers another +15% which gives a final dodge change of 53.9%.

Obviously, these are not additive percentages but I am having trouble figuring out the formula involved. What is actually happening to my Dodge Change when I gain +15% Dodge? If it helps, my Monk is level 56 and currently in Hell.

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67147/how-does-dodge-work-exactly

Comment: @fbueckert Very similar, and possibly is a duplicate, however I personally think it isn't, it seems the other question is more asking how dodge mechanics work, not really how the equations work, while that's what this question is asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dodge percentages multiply out. First, start by thinking of x% dodge as (100-x)% chance to be hit. Specifically, 15% dodge = 85% chance to be hit.

75% base => 25% dodge
75% base * 85% from passive = 63.75% chance to be hit => 36.25% chance to dodge
75% base * 85% from passive * 85% from mantra = 54.1875% chance to be hit => 45.8125% chance to dodge

... and so on. The dex->dodge conversion is also non-linear, but it's not the usual x / (y + x) formula.

Comment: ... yes. Yes it is. Fixed. :)

Comment: Actually, you're wrong when you say that "unlike most other stats". ALL defensive stats in Diablo 3 multiply together (in %), it seems that only offensive stats do not

Comment: Fixed. Because of the rating-based nature of the other stats, I expected there to be effects that boosted the rating directly, but it turns out there aren't any :)

Answer (score 3):

Catalept answered already while I was typing this; so I'm leaving out the detailed explanation, but posting as it explains your actual scenario.

The calculation is multiplicative; so

- Base dodge: 0.25
- Guardian's Path (15%): 0.15
- Mantra of Evasion: 0.15
- Evasion first 3 secs: 0.15

would result in

(1 - 0.25)(1 - 0.15)(1 - 0.15)(1 - 0.15)
= 0.75 * 0.85 * 0.85 * 0.85
= 0.46059375 ~= 0.461

So you have 46.1% chance to be hit; ie. 53.9% dodge