# Do things like Lifesteal and Knockback stack?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I have 2 pieces of gear which both have knockback at 2.0%, do I get a 4% total?

What about if I have gear with lifesteal and use a passive skill (like **Bloodthirst** for the Barbarian) to increase my lifesteal? Do they stack?

Comment: They certainly should, but be aware that life steal and CC effects have diminishing results in higher difficulties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get bonuses from multiple sources for almost any skill and it will stack.

**Life Steal** from weapons, armor, passive skills (`Bloodthirst`), active skills (`Furious Charge`/`Dreadnought`) is additive, you will get the total amount which is then [reduced per difficulty level](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69894/8462).
The contribution of a skill or item to the stat isn't reduced, but its actual effect changes - so e.g. you'd need to get 50% life steal in Inferno to get 10% leeching.

Unlike other games (incl. Diablo 2), most of these don't have hard caps as the lower bonus values effectively soft cap the maximum amounts you can obtain. One notable exception is **Run Speed**, which is capped to 25% from items but can be raised further by skills (e.g. `Sprint`).

Also, **Dodge** has a non-linear relation to Dexterity, and stacks [multiplicatively](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73376/how-do-dodge-skills-and-passives-stack-in-diablo-3) from sources so it may be non-intuitive on how much adding some equipment will increase the stat.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but the other answer said that skills aren't reduced. Are you sure they are reduced too? The source you linked to seems to think they are reduced too.

Comment: Added more info on life leech in Inferno; does that help or were you asking about RS or dodge?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, they do stack both. "Life steal" is however diminished by a factor 5 in inferno. You'll be able to use it up to hell. You should stack "Life on Hit" for inferno.